# Android devices not allowed to connect to WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, router

I am a college student and they provide us free WiFi here . When trying to connect to the WiFi all devices connect to it instantly except Android devices. When Android 6.0 was launched the devices having Android 6.0 could connect to the WiFi , devices like iPhone , windows phone and blackberry connect easily . I have a rooted Android Phone (not Android 6.0) so i changed my MAC Address but still couldn't connect.

How does the router segment devices based on their OS ?

How can I make my Android device connect to the WiFi?

Comment: You should probably talk to your IT department. Without knowing a lot about the network configuration there won't be much we can do for you.

Comment: +1 for the @eldarerathis comment. Its possible they find Android "riskier", since they are rootable, and are perceived as security risks to the network. They may require some VPN, if they allow connections at all.

Comment: @eldarerathis the IT department told me that they have done an OS block in the network , no Android devices can connect to it. Since I have a rooted device ,  I wana know what parameters should I change in my device so that the router does not identify my device as an Android device or anything like that.

Comment: @MohitBadwal you need to change the MAC adress to one of the allowed devices (preferably an Apple one, if iPhones are allowed) and set your hostname as well (or simply don't provide one). The most important part about this are the first 3 octets of the MAC that specify the manufacturer. After that you may impersonate anything you like, you have a rooted phone after all.